# Unable to access jarfile in R

Tags: java, r, jar, rstudio

I am running a `java` command in `Rstudio`, as `system("java -jar ~/OneDrive/Documents/NaCo/Assignment_2/negsel2.jar -self ~/OneDrive/Documents/NaCo/Assignment_2/english.train -n 10 -r 3 -c -l < combined.test")`.

Where the location of the jar and the file is as follow [image: location]

However, I am getting an error: `Unable to access jarfile ~/OneDrive/Documents/NaCo/Assignment_2/negsel2.jar`

I'm not sure what caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this in R is not having an appropriate JAVA runtime installed followed closely by path issues (in my experience).

Take a look at [this article](https://www.developer.com/java/data/getting-started-with-r-using-java/) and see if you can figure out where you are at